# How can I modify a object of my choice in a react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, state

When the button is clicked how can I change `foo2` to `e.target.value`, without affecting the other objects?

```
import React from 'react'

export const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    foo1: "12", foo2: 2, foo3: null
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="" onClick={(e) => setState()}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `foo1: "12", foo2: 2, foo3: null` Consider an array instead. If the properties aren't that related to each other, consider separate states instead of putting them in a single big state object to make updating easier.

Comment: My biggest problem is that I don't know how to transfer states one by one to another component. @CertainPerformance

Comment: If you want to pass down all the values, having a single state object can be more reasonable. `<SomeComp state={state} />`

Answer (score 1):

Use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
setState({ ...state, foo2: e.target.value })
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "other objects" you mean the other values in the state object then you can do the following using Javascript's spread operator `setState({ ...state, foo2: 1 });`
As an alternative, you could also use separate `useState` hooks for the individual values if they don't go together logically. However, you may not care for the extra boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `name` attribute to the button, and use it to update the state by spreading the original state, and overriding the attribute `[target.name]` with the `target.value`:

```js
const { useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    foo1: "12", foo2: 2, foo3: null
  })
  
  const update = ({ target }) => {
    setState(s => ({ ...s, [target.name]: target.value }))
  }
  
  console.log(state)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" name="foo1" value="" onClick={update}>Foo 1</button>
      <button type="button" name="foo2" value="" onClick={update}>Foo 2</button>
      <button type="button" name="foo3" value="" onClick={update}>Foo 3</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```